# heroku deployment problems app not compitable

Tags: python, heroku

I am uploading my project to heroku but it says

```
-----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz
       More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
 !     Push failed
```

but
I have requirements.txt. Any help?

Comment: Is your requirements.txt file at the root of your project, or in a subfolder?

Comment: It is in sub folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `requirements.txt` file needs to be at the root of your GIT repository.

If you don't wish to do so, you can use the [monorepo](https://github.com/lstoll/heroku-buildpack-monorepo) unofficial buildpack which will let you configure a config var with the name of the subfolder you with to deploy.